# Related Products Count

Tags: magento-1.9

If this is a dumb question, apologies - but I'm putting related products on a product, I've moved it from the side bar to the main content area.

All is going well, but its displaying 4 products, I want to show 5.

I found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482486/how-to-display-only-3-related-product-on-product-view-page-magento

And none of the options in there work.

Not sure if I'm missing anything hilariously simple, but wondering if anyone had any ideas. Incidentally I don't want to install a plugin/module or whatever for this. Just call 5 products rather than 4.

Thanks, help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the accepted answer in the post you reference isn't working. Are you certain that you're editing the right template? ie: `related.phtml` in the `rwd` package versus the one in the `base` package. Also, you said it gives 4 and not 5 related products. If there's no limit imposed on the collection anywhere else in the related products block, then perhaps there really only *are* 4 related products.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response @vBuck 

So after all that, I discovered the problem was that the site had an index management lock problem so products weren't being indexed correctly so the product wasn't being applied correctly...

I deleted all locks in var/locks and all is well. But thanks, your suggestion put me on the right track in a roundabout way!

Magento, the Internet Explorer of the ecommerce world :)

Thanks so much for your help, another thing to note down for quirky ways to fix things...

Comment: Good to know for me also. You should post that as your answer so this question can be closed and helpful to others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses to this - but typically the problem was symptomatic of something else, namely the site I was working on had got itself into an index lock, so any products set to be a related product were not being indexed as such. So therefore wouldn't show as related.

So to fix this I went to var/locks and simply deleted all the locks in there and reindexed everything and all was well.

Thanks for everyones help and the solutions mentioned above do work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this method

```
Mage::registry('current_product')->getRelatedProductIds();
```

You can make a condition using:

```
count(Mage::registry('current_product')->getRelatedProductIds());
```

in **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml**

***Remember to copy the basis for your theme.***